# struts 2.2.1 appends ".action" suffix to name

Tags: struts2

My project changed version of struts from struts-2.1.8.1 to struts-2.2.1. 
We don't use suffix ".action" for naming, after migration it is appeared. For older version html code looks like:

```
<form id="Login" name="Login" action="/fm2/Login" method="post">
```

But new struts renders the same form:

```
<form id="Login" name="Login" action="/fm2/Login.action" method="post"
```

So difference that .action has been added. What's wrong with new release?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the default extension (and should be in 2.1.8.1 too).

You can change it in your struts.xml:

```
<constant name="struts.action.extension" value="whatever" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a similiar problem when change to struts-2.2.1 from struts-2.1.8.1.
Struts-2.2.1 will add the ".action" extension automatically for redirectAction result.
This is very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

This has not changed, AFAIK. Be sure to understand the difference between the "struts action" and the ["action attribute of a HTML FORM" element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-action)

Typically, to render a FORM tag in Struts2 you'd use a (Struts2) [form tag](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1/docs/form.html) - its *action* attribute corresponds to the name of a Struts2 action, which corresponds to a url without the suffix (by default '.action', but you can change it)

So, the Struts2 tag

```
<s:form action="/fm2/Login">
```

would typically produce the HTML output

```
<form action="/fm2/Login.action">
```

Comment: Cannot see th logic. Two different versions of struts produce different HTML(!) code. So I don't mix the action and form of HTML, but get some side effect with new suffix.

Comment: "Two different versions of struts produce different HTML(!) code. " No, they don't -AFAIK. Show us an example if you found otherwise.

Comment: read attentively my question. I have provided the example. The source of project wasn't changed, only version of struts.

Comment: you didn't provided the code of the jsp that produced that html, nor the relevant configuration sections (struts.action.extension )

Comment: And a more fundamental thing: you say "We don't use suffix ".action" for naming" . So what suffix do you use in your urls? An empty one ? That must be configured somewhere. (if not, ".action" is the default)

Answer (score 0):

I removed the struts2-convention-plugin-2.1.8.1 jar from my web-inf/lib and it started to work fine.
Hope this helps...
cheers...